# Equation of Directrix of a Parabola

Tags: calculus, geometry, conic-sections

> Find the equation of the directrix of the  parabola $y^2+4y+4x+2=0$

I tried it as follows:

$$(y+2)^2+4x-2=0$$
$$(y+2)^2=-4(x-\frac{1}{2})$$
On comparing with $Y^2=-4aX, a>0$, I got $a=1$
Thus, the  equation of the directrix is $X=a\Rightarrow X-1=0$.
Since the origin has been shifted, the equation is 
$$x-\frac12-1=0$$
$$2x-3$$

However this answer is apparently wrong. This lead to another doubt. For  this question, I assumed that the Directrix was parallel to the $Y$ axis.  Was I correct in making this assumption? When can we/can't we make this assumption of the Directrix being parallel to one of the axes?

Many thanks in anticipation.

Comment: It seans correct. The directirx has equation $x=3/2$. If in the equation there s not a mixed term in $ xy$ than you can be sure that the axis of symmetry of the conic is parallel to one of the coordinate axis, and so the direcrtix that is orthogonal to the symmetry axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct. If you want you can memorize some formulas:

a parabola of equation $x=ay^2+by+c\;$  has the symmetry axis $s$ parallel to  the $x$ axis and its equation is:

$s \quad: \quad y=\dfrac{-b}{2a}=h$

The vertex is at:  $ \quad V\quad : \quad \left(x(h),h \right)=(k,h)$

The focus is at : $\quad F \quad :\quad (k+p,h)\; $ with $p=\dfrac{1}{4a}$

and the directrix has equation:

$d \quad : \quad x=k-p$

We can easily see that for your parabola $x=-\frac{1}{4}y^2-y-\frac{1}{2}$ the directrix is the line $x=\frac{3}{2}$.

Note that , as for all the conics , the axis of symmetry is parallel  to one of the coordinate axis iff the equation does not contain a mixed term in $xy$.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Lastly Sir, is it true for all Conics that the Vertex always bisects the distance between the focus and the directrix, or is it just for Parabolas?

Comment: Just for parabolas. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Eccentricity.2C_focus_and_directrix